# Add all checked checkboxes android

Tags: java, android

my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="Select Products"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buy"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="92dp"
    android:text="Pay" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/cb2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:text="Casual Shirt - 400 Rs" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buy"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cb3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
    android:text="t-Shirt - 200 Rs" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cb2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Shorts - 300 Rs" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/cb3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cb1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:text="Jeans - 500 Rs" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

java file

```
package com.example.multiactivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MaleActivity extends Activity {

Button b1;
CheckBox cb1, cb2, cb3, cb4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.male);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buy);
    cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
    cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb2);
    cb3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb3);
    cb4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb4);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String added = "";

            if (cb1.isChecked()) {

                int a = 400;

            }
            if (cb2.isChecked()) {

                int b = 500;
            }
            if (cb3.isChecked()) {

                int c = 300;
            }
            if (cb4.isChecked()) {

                int d = 200;
            } else {

                return;

            }

        }

    });

}

}
```

I am trying to add all selected checkboxes.

I am trying to get the total of all added products.

I am unable to select all checkedboxes for the total figure.

I want to add the selected int and get the total

ex. int a + b + c;

Help

Thanks.

Comment: If you want them to be selected at the start just add `android:checked="true"` to each of them in xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your `onClick()` method could be this instead

```
    String added;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int a = 0;
        if (cb1.isChecked()) a+=400;
        if (cb2.isChecked()) a+=500;
        if (cb3.isChecked()) a+=300;
        if (cb4.isChecked()) a+=200;
        added = Integer.toString(a);
    }
```

I don't really know why the checkboxes wouldn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're saying if a box is checked, then set an `int` to a value.

If your values are static, just initalize them ahead of time and do something like

```
int sum = 0;


            if (cb1.isChecked()) {

                sum += 400;

            }
```

edit: if your clickability is a problem refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aclickable

Comment: I cannot use toast inside onclicklistner. Is there any alternative to display the total of selected products.

Comment: Yes, set up a TextView and use setText() method to change the text to your sum with each check.

Comment: @Whackyy you can actually use a toast inside onClickListener. You can show it like this `Toast.makeText(MaleActivity.this, "total = " + total, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: It should. onClickListener does not exclude Toast. What error are you getting? Have you tried setting a TextView and using setText()?

Answer (score 0):

use this java file (please, note the comment at the end of the "onClick" function)

```
package com.example.multiactivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MaleActivity extends Activity {

Button b1;
CheckBox cb1, cb2, cb3, cb4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.male);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buy);
    cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
    cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb2);
    cb3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb3);
    cb4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb4);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String added = "";
            int sum = 0;

            if (cb1.isChecked()) {

                sum += 400;

            }
            if (cb2.isChecked()) {

                sum += 500;
            }
            if (cb3.isChecked()) {

                sum += 300;
            }
            if (cb4.isChecked()) {

                sum += 200;
            }

            //now in "sum" you have the sum

        }

    });

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a private field called total

```
private int total;

b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String added = "";
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
        int d = 0;

        if (cb1.isChecked()) {

            a = 400;

        }
        if (cb2.isChecked()) {

            b = 500;
        }
        if (cb3.isChecked()) {

            c = 300;
        }
        if (cb4.isChecked()) {

            d = 200;
        } 

        total = a + b + c + d; // or total += a + b + c + d;
    }
}
```

and then you can use total wherever you want

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you had better replace your code with this

```
HashMap<String,Boolean> items = new HashMap<>();
checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.onCheckedChangeListener(){
@Override
public void onCheckedChange(CompundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked){
if(isChecked){items.put("order982929",true);}
}
});
```

Continue with other checkboxes and finally convert this HashMap to json and send it to your server

Answer (score 0):

After clicking  pay button App stops.

```
// MaleActivity.java
package com.example.multiactivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MaleActivity extends Activity {

Button b1;
CheckBox cb1, cb2, cb3, cb4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.male);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buy);
    cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
    cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb2);
    cb3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb3);
    cb4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb4);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int sum = 0;

            if (cb1.isChecked()) {

                sum += 400;

            }
            if (cb2.isChecked()) {

                sum += 500;
            }
            if (cb3.isChecked()) {

                sum += 300;
            }
            if (cb4.isChecked()) {

                sum += 200;
            }

            int a = sum;
            Intent i = new Intent(MaleActivity.this, LastPage.class);
            i.putExtra("total", a);
            startActivity(i);

        }

    });

}

}
```

My lastpage activity.

```
//LastPage.java

package com.example.multiactivity;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LastPage extends Activity {

TextView t2;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.last_page);

    t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


    Intent i= getIntent();
    Bundle b = i.getExtras();

    if(b!=null)
    {
        String j =(String) b.get("total");
        t2.setText("Your Total is "+ j);
    }
}

}
```

App stops.

Help

thanks